# Changing actor material when hit by player projectile UE4

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal

I am attempting to make a cube that changes color from preset material made in the Unreal Editor.

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.

//added constructor helpers, engine, and Kismet
#include "ColorChangingCube.h"
#include "UObject/ConstructorHelpers.h"
#include "Engine.h"
#include "Kismet/KismetMathLibrary.h"
#include "Kismet/KismetRenderingLibrary.h"

// Sets default values
AColorChangingCube::AColorChangingCube()
{
    // Set this actor to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

    //initializing mesh comp and setting it as Root comp
    CubeMesh = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(TEXT("CubeMesh"));
    RootComponent = CubeMesh;

    //making construction helper using this model
    static ConstructorHelpers::FObjectFinder<UStaticMesh>asset(TEXT("StaticMesh'/Game/Geometry/Meshes/1M_Cube.1M_Cube'"));

    //setting mesh to constructions helper
    CubeMesh->SetStaticMesh(asset.Object);


}

// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void AColorChangingCube::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();


    
}

// Called every frame
void AColorChangingCube::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);

}

void AColorChangingCube::ChangeColor()
{
    //calling green material and naming it GreenMat
    static ConstructorHelpers::FObjectFinder<UMaterial>GreenMat(TEXT("Material'/Game/FirstPerson/Material/Green.Green'"));

    //calling red material and naming it RedMat
    static ConstructorHelpers::FObjectFinder<UMaterial>RedMat(TEXT("Material'/Game/FirstPerson/Material/Red.Red'"));

    //applying GreenMat as default material on actor
    CubeMesh = GreenMat;
    //if statements verifying green and red dynamic material instance
    if (GreenMat.Object != NULL)
    {
        mInterface = (UMaterial*)GreenMat.Object;
    }

    if (RedMat.Object != NULL)
    {
        mInterface = (UMaterial*)RedMat.Object;
    }

    //if dynamic material is created, this creates it
    if (mInterface)
    {
        MatInstance = UMaterialInstanceDynamic::Create(mInterface, this);
    }

    //checks to see if MatInstance is set
    if (MatInstance)
    {
        CubeMesh->SetMaterial(0, MatInstance);
    }
}
```

I at first was getting a hard crash in engine when shooting the actor. I have tried applying a 'default' material GreenMat on the actor on line 54 but it is not a compile error. Already edited my projectile class to successfully call the ColorChange. Code for that below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
void APaintballMichaelMProjectile::OnHit(UPrimitiveComponent* HitComp, AActor* OtherActor, UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComp, FVector NormalImpulse, const FHitResult& Hit)
{
    //variable for ColorChangingCube and if statement
    AColorChangingCube* ColorActor = Cast<AColorChangingCube>(OtherActor);
    if (ColorActor)
    {
        ColorActor->ChangeColor();
    }

    // Only add impulse and destroy projectile if we hit a physics
    if ((OtherActor != nullptr) && (OtherActor != this) && (OtherComp != nullptr) && OtherComp->IsSimulatingPhysics())
    {
        OtherComp->AddImpulseAtLocation(GetVelocity() * 100.0f, GetActorLocation());

        //commented out to prevent destruction
        //Destroy();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So, first of all, what is the goal you're trying to achieve? Since you have two materials `GreenMat` and `RedMat` are you trying to swap between these two colours each time your `AColorChangingCube` is hit, or are you trying to set a random material each time it's hit?

Either way, the first problem I see is within your
`AColorChangingCube::ChangeColor()` function you are trying to use the `ConstructorHelpers` class, this cannot be done from within functions, as the name suggests, `ConstructorHelpers` are only valid to use from your `AColorChangingCube` constructor (defined at the top of your cpp file `AColorChangingCube::AColorChangingCube()`.

Simply move the following lines:

```cpp
//calling green material and naming it GreenMat
static ConstructorHelpers::FObjectFinder<UMaterial>GreenMat(TEXT("Material'/Game/FirstPerson/Material/Green.Green'"));

//calling red material and naming it RedMat
static ConstructorHelpers::FObjectFinder<UMaterial>RedMat(TEXT("Material'/Game/FirstPerson/Material/Red.Red'"));
```

Under this line `CubeMesh->SetStaticMesh(asset.Object);` in the constructor.

Once that's done, you just need to fix your logic in the `AColorChangingCube::ChangeColor()` function, if you can post/link to your whole `ColorChangingCube.h` and `ColorChangingCube.cpp` files with a better explantion of what the exact behaviour you intend for, I can provide a better answer.